# sizeof std::aligned_storage the actual available storage size?

Tags: c++, c++11, libc++

Does the standard somehow guarantee that `sizeof(typename aligned_storage<...>::type)` is the actual available size of data that can be written into the aligned storage starting at it's address?  The reason I ask this is that I am implementing a std::function style object which avoids heap allocations if the object will fit into some small aligned_storage.

I looked at the libc++ implementation of std::function constructors (which do just that), and the test they perform to make sure the passed type will fit into the aligned storage is just...

```
if (sizeof(_FF) <= sizeof(__buf_) && is_nothrow_copy_constructible<_Fp>::value)
{
    __f_ = (__base*)&__buf_;
    ::new (__f_) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f));
}
```

Where `__buf_` is aligned_storage, `_FF` is the wrapper class for the type erasured passed functor, and `_Fp` is that functor type.

I'm assuming that this is NOT guaranteed, and it (probably?) just happens as a result of the libc++ implementation of aligned_storage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is not guaranteed.  That `sizeof(X)` is the size of `X`?  If you can write anywhere within a POD's data and treat it as plain old data?

Comment: That you can write `sizeof(__buf_)` bytes starting at `&__buf_`.  For example, the actual aligned storage used in libc++ is `typename aligned_storage<3*sizeof(void*)>::type __buf_;`  which has (on my machine) sizeof = 32, and `3*sizeof(void*)` = 24, so the check against the sizeof(__buf_) is actually going 8 bytes past what we requested to std::aligned_storage, and obviously the placement constructor could then write outside the aligned storage.

Comment: @pat: The placement constructor couldn't write outside the aligned storage, you got that backwards.  The placement constructor would use only the first part of the storage, with some "padding" leftover.  Unrelated, it's seems weird to me that `aligned_storage` would give you extra space, though tests confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::aligned_storage<len, align>::type` is a POD type.  This means it is plain old data.

How it came to be does not matter.  It is merely plain old data.

Now, it has additional guarantees.  It also can be used for aligned storage for an object of size `len` with alignment requirements `align`, but those additional requirement do not reduce its guarantees as plain old data.

And plain old data is what it says: plain old data.

A POD type can be copied into an array, and copied to from an array, and afterwards it has the "same state".  Such a copy can consists of its full size (`[basic.types]` 3.9/2).  There are more similar guarantees for particular behavior.

In theory, I suspect that assignment/copying might not copy every byte in the POD, but doing so is safe.

I suppose you could have a type which represents some kind of masked memory so that `memcpy` ignores some bytes transparently, and as the value of the type is only held by some of the bytes but not others the ignored bytes are not a problem to the guarantees from 3.9, but that is both questionable and not the implementation used by any compiler I could think of.

Comment: § 3.9\4 says that for the trivially copiable types, all bits are considered in the value representation, and each value-representations represents a distinct value.  That means that the copy must preserve all bits.

Comment: @MooingDuck I can read 3.9\4, but I don't see that interpretation.  "For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value" -- "a set of bits ... that determine a value".  How does that guarantee all bits are used?  (using N3797 here).  Basically, this is POD: `struct foo { char a; int b; }`, yet padding is likely between `a` and `b`, so those bytes do not impact the *value* of `foo`.  Magic memory that made memcpy do nothing to those bytes seems legal?

Comment: "For trivially copyable types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an implementation-defined set of values."  Each bit of the object representation (all bits in sizeof(T)) partakes in the value.  If you copy one instance to another location, it must have the same value.  Since all bits partake in the value, it must therefore also have all the same bits.

Comment: @MooingDuck Again, you say "Each bit of the object representation (all bits in sizeof(T)) partakes in the value.", but that is your words, not the standards.  "a set of bits in the object representation" does not mean "every bit in the object representation" as far as I can tell.  So, where are you getting **every bit is important** from?  And what about my toy `struct` (above, from an edit), with likely padding: clearly the bytes in padding do not change the `struct`'s value!

Comment: Oh, I was reading as "the value representation is _the_ set of bits in the object representation", but you're right, that's not what it says.  My bad.